# Notice: Undefined index: username PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have spent some time looking for answers on the net and to no avail - read some of the posts, but have not seen something that is the same.

The following line is causing me an issue with the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\newlogin\authorise.php on line 19
```

The line it is associated with is the following:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':username',strtolower($_POST['username']));
```

I have included all of the code just in case. I have the username column setup in the database (MySQL)

Any advice would be great, am fairly new to this, so my apologies if there is a simple response

---

```
<title>authorise</title>
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"

try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login_site","root","black$23");

}

catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$query = "select  * from 'users' where LOWER ('username')=:username";
$stmt=$dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':username',strtolower($_POST['username']));<--- issue is on this line
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->rowCount()==1){
    echo'user found';
}
```

---

Comment: use `isset($_POST['username'])`

Comment: you probably submitted the form without typing a username

Comment: Please post your html as well.

Comment: html:<form method="post" action="authorise.php">
Username: <input type ="text" name"username"/><br/>
Password: <input type ="password" name="password"/><br/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>

Answer (score 2):

It means that your $_POST array doesn't have username key.

You can simply check it with if

```
if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
    $query = "select  * from 'users' where LOWER ('username')=:username";
    $stmt=$dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':username',strtolower($_POST['username']));
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->rowCount()==1)
    {
        echo'user found';
    }
}
```

Voila no notice ;)

When you post form check if the input name is set to "username" and is not empty.

Comment: I get a blank page when I put this code in. Thought I should get the user found text

Comment: add else { echo 'username is empty'; } you don't get data  from your form as I wrote in answer check name of inputs.

Comment: It apphe ears as if the code is not getting to the if statement - have echoed inside the if statement and I am still getting a blank page. Have you somemore advice?

Comment: It appears as if the code is not reaching the if statement with the username information, i tried it instead of the code I have been using and there is no display. I have also tried echoing inside the if statement and there is no display. Could you please help?

Comment: maybe turn on errors and check what's happening with error_reporting(E_ALL) or ini_set('display_errors' 1)

Answer (score 0):

It means either you dont have username fild in your database table or you dont have username field name in your form. Please double check your table structure and form.

Comment: I do have the username in the database and I have the username field in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that I missed out on an = sign in the login script. However, I am still the authorise page will not enter the if statement. I have put echos in and around it and they display until I put the echo inside the if statement